# Howto make editing OpenLDAP Schema possible with cn=config Backend and without ldapmodify?

Tags: schema, openldap

I try to setup an openLDAP server to manage a central addressbook which will primarily be used in MS Outlook. Still wondering, why there still is no out-of-the-box scheme implemented which provides all necessary fields, im stuck by the new `cn=config` backend.

I have no `slapd.conf` as all information is stored in the new backend. It's said, that I have to use `ldapmodify` to make changes to the configuration and schema-files. It is very inconvenient to me to do all the changes on CLI, I want to know, how to change the standard configuraion, to be able to make such modification with an LDAP tool of my choice on a remote machine.

At the moment, the only ways to modify the configuration are:

- editing the data files while `slapd` is not executed
- using `ldapmodify` with external authentication (e.g. `ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f modifications.ldif`)

Both methods are not what I want.

I tried to modify the config-backend-files to make it possible, but simply adding a RootPW didn't do the trick. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't

> said [you] have to use `ldapmodify`

at all. You can use any LDAP client to modify the configuration. There are many:

- [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/),
- [Userbooster](http://www.userbooster.de/),
- [...](https://www.google.com/search?q=LDAP%20client)

Comment: Yes I want to. But all I use get an "insufficient access" error as soon as I try to modify a schema. Data modification is possible but for modifying a schema an external authentication is required, which can only be done on the CLI of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `olcRootPW` to the entry `dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` should work.

If it still does not work, try to

- `slapcat` the `cn=config` database to `/path/to/file/slapd.conf.ldif` (for example)
- Modify the entry `dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` to add the attribute `olcRootPW: YourPassword`
- `slapadd` the modified LDIF : `slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -b cn=config -l /path/to/file/slapd.conf.ldif`

Every thing need to be done while `slapd` is stopped.